# How to retrieve referenced documents in Firestore?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-cloud-firestore

I have a React web app where I am trying to manage orders and tables.

I have a collection of `tables` and a collection of `orders`.

A table has a field of `orders` which is an array of referenced documents.

I want to be able to retrieve via snapshop listener, the list of orders for a table.

I currently have a function to add an item to an order which updates my orders and table collections.

```
const addToOrder = async () => {
    try {
      const orderRef = await addDoc(collection(db, "orders/"), menu[0]);
      const tablesRef = await updateDoc(doc(db, `tables/Pieu2dZ6GX9WpVKCU7kY`), {
        orders: arrayUnion(orderRef)
      });    
      console.log("Document written with ID: ", tablesRef);
    } catch (e) {
      console.error("Error adding document: ", e);
    }
  }
```

I then try listen to these changes with the `onSnapshot` function:

```
try {
      onSnapshot(doc(db, 'tables/Pieu2dZ6GX9WpVKCU7kY'), async (doc) => {
        console.log("Current data: ", doc.data());
        
      });
    }catch(err) {
      console.log("err:", err)
    }
```

This only returns an array of orders which doesn't have the referenced document in it. It just returns this:

```
// removed some data to obfuscate config
{
    "converter": null,
    "_key": {
        "path": {
            "segments": [],
            "offset": 5,
            "len": 2
        }
    },
    "type": "document",
    "firestore": {
        "app": {
            "_isDeleted": false,
            "_options": {
            },
            "_config": {
                "name": "[DEFAULT]",
                "automaticDataCollectionEnabled": false
            },
            "_name": "[DEFAULT]",
            "_automaticDataCollectionEnabled": false,
            "_container": {
                "name": "[DEFAULT]",
                "providers": {}
            }
        },
        "databaseId": {
            "projectId": "oats-e82ae",
            "database": "(default)"
        },
        "settings": {
            "host": "firestore.googleapis.com",
            "ssl": true,
            "ignoreUndefinedProperties": false,
            "cacheSizeBytes": 41943040,
            "experimentalForceLongPolling": false,
            "experimentalAutoDetectLongPolling": false,
            "useFetchStreams": true
        }
    }
}
```

Do I have my collections setup correctly? Should I be using one collection for tables and another orders that then reference each other?

If so, how should I be retrieving related docs on

Screenshot of console log:

[image]

Comment: That doesn't at all look like the result of a call to `doc.data()`.  Are you looking at the right thing? BTW logging `tablesRef` isn't going to show you a document ID.  [updateDoc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firestore_lite.md#updatedoc) returns a promise of void.

Comment: Thanks Doug. My log output above may have been slightly off so I have attached a screenshot to show that the log returns an objects with an array of `orders` which contains the object result aforementioned. Hope this makes more sense

Comment: What are you expecting that's different than what you've got?  You are only writing an array field "orders", and that's exactly what your doc output shows.  Each one of those array items contains a DocumentReference, which is what I'd expect.

Comment: What I don't understand is how I should retrieve those referenced documents. Do I need to perform a `getDocs` on each of those or does Firestore have a way of querying "related" documents?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is effectively pushing DocumentReference objects into an array field of another document.  It is **not** storing the contents of the order doc inside the tables dock just a reference.  When you read the tables document back, you're going to see a list of [DocumentReference](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firestore_.documentreference) objects in that same field.  These DocumentReference objects are just like any other DocumentReference that you might create programmatically, so you can simply [`getDoc()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firestore_#getdoc) on each one if you want its contents.

Comment: Thanks Doug. That makes sense and I assumed that would be the case but wasn't sure if that is the prescribed way of doing things. Thanks for your help